# glOrtho and VBO

Tags: opengl, coordinates, projection, vbo

I'm trying to send triangles to OpenGL using screen coordinates. Using the deprecated **glBegin** and **glEnd** I could just set up an orthographic projection and use screen-space coordinates as the triangles/quads coords. I figured I needed to do just that using VBO but for some reason no matter what values I set on glOrtho will not change where the triangle is drawn (which makes it seem it's not using the coordinate system I've given the glOrtho function).

Here's how I set up glOrtho:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1); // Origin in upper-left corner
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

And here's my shaders:

**Vertex**

```
#version 300 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;  //set the frist input on location (index) 0 ; in_position is our attribute 

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment**

```
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

Setting up the VBO:

```
unsigned int vao;
unsigned int vbo;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

float vertices[][3] ={
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f}
};

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, (void*)0);
```

Finally the draw loop is just:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1.0, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);

glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glXSwapBuffers(display, win);
```

And an accompanying image showing where the triangle is being drawn:

[image: triangle]

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Any particular reason for mixing old and deprecated old OpenGL (`glOrtho`) with the "new" one(VBO)? I would not even expect the two different pipeline work together...

Comment: I was not aware glOrtho was also deprecated. Can you point me to how to achieve the same results as with glOrtho in modern OpenGL?

Comment: Just pick any new OpenGL tutorial you like and relace the part where 3D projection matrix is constructed with ortho matrix. The GLM library(the tutorial will be likely using glm already) will help you to construct one.